# Is it safe to save files in python library?

Tags: python, python-turtle, lib, pytube

I wanted to use python turtle and the code didn't work, until I saved the file in the python library. (it didn't work earlier giving an error message saying 'turtle' is not recognised)

When i saved the file in the library, i saved the file as “hello23.py” but it got saved in the library as "pytube-pytube-v12.0.0-0-ge85.py”

It's been saved by the same name of the pytube file. (“pytube” is  the package used to download YouTube videos by python.) Why is that?

And I saved another file again by creating a new folder in the library. it got saved fine.

My OS is Mac, Is it safe to save files in the library? I’ve heard not to save user files in the library.

Comment: I doubt that the file renamed itself. But to answer your question: you should leave the Python path alone. If you can't import `turtle` you have some other problem.

Comment: Thank you, but what do you think about the file renaming, I am doubting if it overwrote any file.